# Alignment inside itemize command

Tags: itemize

please can someone provide help with my issue ? I am getting struggle with text alignment in "itemize" command. I need to align first column from left and second one from left also like is presented on picture.

Thank you for help. [image: as you see, described words are align from left and its descriptions are too.]

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Could you please post whatever code you have so that people can have a look at it? It's difficult to do anything with just a picture when we do not know what document class, packages, commands you are using etc. You can edit your question to include the code please, it's right underneath your image next to "share", thank you

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a `longtable`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [enumitem package](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en), you could use the `align=left` option. You'll also need to make your `labelindent` and `leftmargin` sizes nice and generous; you may need to tweak the exact widths.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[align=left,labelwidth=8em,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=10em]
\item[Li-ion]   Litium-Ion battery
\item[Li-O]     Litium-Oxigen
\item[Li-S]     Litium-Sulfur
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: itemize align example]

It's also possible that you'd be better off with a longtable, as suggested in the comments, depending on how you want to handle long entries on the right.